# Cygwin: unable to clone: "already exist and is not an empty directory", but directory does not exist

Tags: git, cygwin

I have a strange issue. I want to clone from a git repo, which fails, apparently cause the target directory already exists and is not empty:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 --branch "main" https://github.com/papanito/zi.git $HOME/.zi/bin/
fatal: destination path '/cygdrive/c/Users/papanito/.zi/bin' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

But I can confirm, the directory does not exist

```
$ ls -al $HOME/.zi/
ls: cannot access '/cygdrive/c/Users/papanito/.zi/': No such file or directory
```

This is my `/etc/nssswitch.conf`

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
#    This file is read once by the first process in a Cygwin process tree.
#    To pick up changes, restart all Cygwin processes.  For a description
#    see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch
#
# Defaults:
# passwd:   files db
# group:    files db
# db_enum:  cache builtin
# db_home:  /home/%U
# db_shell: /bin/bash
# db_gecos: <empty>

db_home: windows
```

I found that cygwin is actually looking here

```
/cygdrive/c/cygdrive/c/Users/papanito/
```

So if I check there is actually the folder `.zi`

```
ls -al /cygdrive/c/cygdrive/c/Users/papanito/
total 0
drwxrwx---+ 1 papanito Domain Users 0 Oct 21 15:55 ./
drwxrwx---+ 1 papanito Domain Users 0 Oct 21 15:55 ../
drwxrwx---+ 1 papanito Domain Users 0 Oct 21 15:55 .zi/
```

The `$HOME` variable seems fine though

```
echo $HOME
/cygdrive/c/Users/papanito
```

Here the mount info

```
$ mount
C:/Users/papanito/scoop/persist/cygwin/root/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/Users/papanito/scoop/persist/cygwin/root/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/Users/papanito/scoop/persist/cygwin/root on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Comment: This is just a WAG, but could it have something to do with symbolic links? Their syntax is slightly different between Linux and Windows for starters, and cygwin can use different implementation rules depending on the setting of the `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:...` variable. Search on `cygwin.com` for more info.

Comment: Thanks @DougHenderson but I a not sure that is it. I mean it's a fresh install of Cygwin and the only thing I changed is `db_home: windows`

Answer (score 0):

I can workaround the issue by executing this

```
mklink /J C:\cygdrive\c\Users\papanito C:\Users\papanito\
```